# What's the problem in this program of Single Linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

     struct node {
        int data;
    struct node* nextptr;
     } * manode;

    void add();
    void delete ();
    void display();

    int main()
    {
    int choice;

    int echoice;
    while (choice != 4) {
        printf("\n \t ENTER YOUR CHOICE FOR SINGLE LINKED LIST ");
        printf("\n \t 1. ADD ELEMENT ");
        printf("\n \t 2. DISPLAY ELEMENT ");
        printf("\n \t 3. DELETE ELEMENT ");
        printf("\n \t 4. EXIT  ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            while (echoice != 0) {
                add();
                printf("\n DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE 1/0 ");
                scanf("%d", &echoice);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            display();
            break;
        case 3:
            delete ();
            break;
        case 4:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n \t WRONG VALUE ENTERED ");
        };
    }
    return 0;
}


#Add function is responsible to add the first node and all the remaining nodes as well.



    void add()
{
    struct node *tmp, *tmp2;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tmp2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int value;

    printf("    ENTER THE VALUE YOU WANT TO ENTER   ");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    if (manode == NULL) {
        manode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("  FIRST ENTRY ");
        manode->data = value;
        manode->nextptr = NULL;
        tmp = manode;
        printf("THE DATA %d  ", manode->data);
    }


    else {
        if (tmp2 == NULL) {
            printf("\n MEMORY ALLOCATION FAILED");
        }
        else {
            tmp2->data = value;
            tmp2->nextptr = NULL;
            tmp->nextptr = tmp2;
            tmp = tmp->nextptr;
        }
    }
    //manode=tmp;
}

void display()
{
    struct node* tmp1;
    if (manode == NULL) {
        printf(" MEMORY ALLOCATION FAILED ");
    }
    else {
        tmp1 = manode;
        while (tmp1 != NULL) {
            printf("\n%d  DATA IS DISPLAY \n", tmp1->data);
            tmp1 = tmp1->nextptr;
        }
    }
}

void delete ()
{
    struct node* tmp;
    if (manode == NULL) {
        printf("NOTHING TO DELETE ");
    }
    else {
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    }
}
```

Kindly copy and compile the code, it's working but it doesn't display the contents in the list. Kindly copy and compile the code, it's working but it doesn't display the contents in the list.Kindly copy and compile the code, it's working but it doesn't display the contents in the list.Kindly copy and compile the code, it's working but it doesn't display the contents in the list.

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages, please don't spam with unrelated tags.

Comment: Please create [MRE]

Comment: `add` allocates either two or three nodes, when one would be the appropriate amount.

Comment: `add()` is supposed add exactly one node, right? So why are there not one, not two, but three `malloc`s in there? That doesn't make any sense, as Mr. Spock would say: this is not logical.

Comment: post the code in a way someone can copy and compile, as easy as possible.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Three 'malloc' is needed. It isn't possible to just use one 'malloc' to add nodes and link them properly. In the 'add()' function 'manode' is for the first node, tmp to hols it and tmp2 to link further.

Comment: I'm confident that it is possible to use just one `malloc` in order to add only one node to a linked list. Every time I had to add something to a linked list, I always needed to allocate just one object, instead of three. Only one object gets added to the list, so what do all the other two objects do? There is no law in C++ that requires you to malloc ***every pointer***. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @arfneto I have edited the above code, Kindly do copy and compile and help me out here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But In C, there is no concept of objects, However, It seems that C has its own quasi-objects such as 'structs' that can be considered as objects (in the high-level way that we would normally think).

Comment: Correct, but irrelevant. There is no such law in C either, that requires every declared pointer to point to `malloc`ed memory. C does not work this way, either.

Comment: The thing is I've used three mallocs, just experiment out things. However, I'm pretty sure you cant use just one malloc to implement the above. 
The reason being three mallocs used above is to implement singly linked list through all ways I can think of, And one malloc allocated memory for the first pointer (manode). other is to store malloc and to link it with the next node. It can be done using two mallocs but anyways, I just need to know, What is it in the above code that's putting it off. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: see the code I posted, please

Comment: @arfneto Thanks so much for it, Give me a moment.

Comment: Linked lists don't store pointers. They store values. There is no separate pointer for the value in the list, and the pointer to the next element. There's only one object (or struct), with a pointer. Hence, it's only necessary to `malloc` exactly one thing when adding exactly one thing to a linked list. See your C textbook for more information. If you were to look at a C++ implementation of `std::list`, which is the same as an ordinary linked list, in C or C++, you will be surprised to learn that only one allocation is made when adding a new value. The shown code leaks memory.

Comment: Beyond the `malloc` issue, you don't have any initialized `value` to put in the added record.  But first things first.  Consider that fact that since its is a 'linked list', the important part is the links, aka the pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, there are a number of issues with your code.

- do not use `conio.h`. This thing is from the '80s and adds nothing to a modern program but problems
- never try to implement an ADT --- any container such as list, set, map --- as a node. It will only give you trouble: a list is a collection of nodes. Each node has a payload, some data. This data can have a key, something used to compare records. A node is not a list. A node is not the data. A list is not a node. As seen from the list, the data are the nodes. This way you can use anything as data in your list. And this is the purpose of a container: write once, use always. And the list has metadata, some obvious controls such its size, starting addres, ending address and possibly other stuff.
- do not use `void()`. Is a waste, sometimes an error. In your case is an error. All pointers are buried inside the functions and die there. So `display()` and `add()` does not work
- do not *typedef* pointers. It is a mess. In you case `manode` is a pointer. How are someone, even yourself a few days from now, remember what is what? If `manode` is a typedef for a struct everyone knows that

```
         manode* many_nodes[30]
```

declare `many_nodes` as a pointer to an array of structs. The asterisk tells everything: `many_nodes` is a pointer to `manode`. BTOS if you bury the `*` inside the typedef you will always need to refer to the code in the header.

- do not mix code of the list with I/O. It will only make your like harder. You have a list of simple `int`, so declare `add()` for instance as `int add(int item, List* the_list)`. This way is more readable and you can write a simple loop to fill the list with a few hundred or just one node and start testing.
- if you have a menu just write it as a function that returns the user option. But add it later to the program. A menu serves nothing to the list and to the program
- `scanf()` was not written to read input from the keyboard. It is for scan formatted input, hence the name. It will always give you trouble when reading from stdin. But do your part and at least always test the return of scanf(). ALWAYS. rtfm.
- do not write `\n \t` on a printf. Use just tabs or count the spaces.
- always initialize all variables. In your code you start testing `choice` and `echoice` with no value set.
- what is the point of having a loop on option 1, add since anyway the user will need to input an answer and enter `1`?

#### Back to your program

See below your code rearranged using some of the things I wrote above. Compare with your code

#### Sample Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct st_node
{
    int data;
    struct st_node* nextptr;

}   Node;

typedef struct tlist
{
    unsigned    size;
    Node*       start;

}   List;


int     add(int, List*);
int     delete (int, List*);
int     display(List*);
int     menu();

int         main(void)
{
    List one;
    one.size = 0;
    one.start = NULL;

    int res = menu();
    printf("menu returned %d\n", res);

    display(&one);
    for( int i = 0; i<10; i+=1)
        add(i,&one);
    display(&one);
    return 0;
}

int         add(int value, List* l)
{
    if ( l == NULL ) return -1;
    Node* node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    // simplest: insert at the beginning
    node->nextptr = l->start;
    node->data = value;
    l->start = node;
    l->size += 1;
    return l->size;
};

int         display(List* l)
{
    if ( l== NULL) return -1;
    if ( l->size == 0 )
    {
        printf("\n\tlist is empty\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\t%d elements in the list\n\n", l->size);
    };

    Node* p = l->start;
    for( unsigned i = 0; i< l->size; i+=1)
    {
        printf("%3d: %11d\n", 1+i, p->data);
        p = p->nextptr;
    };
    return l->size;
}

int delete (int v, List* l)
{
    return 0;
}

int         menu()
{
    int choice = 0;
    int res = 0;
    printf(
        "\n\tENTER YOUR CHOICE FOR SINGLE LINKED LIST:\n\
\n\t\t1. ADD ELEMENT\
\n\t\t2. DISPLAY ELEMENT\
\n\t\t3. DELETE ELEMENT\
\n\t\t4. EXIT\
\n\n\t\tYour choice:   ");

   while( res != 1 )
   {
        res = scanf("%d", &choice);
        if ( choice >=1 && choice <= 4 ) return choice;
   };
   return 4;
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
        ENTER YOUR CHOICE FOR SINGLE LINKED LIST:

                1. ADD ELEMENT
                2. DISPLAY ELEMENT
                3. DELETE ELEMENT
                4. EXIT

                Your choice:   2
menu returned 2

        list is empty


        10 elements in the list

  1:           9
  2:           8
  3:           7
  4:           6
  5:           5
  6:           4
  7:           3
  8:           2
  9:           1
 10:           0
```

And it is just an example of stuff using a more manageable list.